# How to perform validation on associative array of field names in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am taking my fields name as associative array in html code in CodeIgniter but am running into trouble when I validate it.

Here is the code I'm using:

**View Page**

```
{<input type="text" name="name[name]">
<?php echo form_error('name[name]'); ?>}
```

**Controller**

```
{$this->form_validation->set_rules('name[name]','name','required');}
```

How might I solve this?

Comment: Please edit your question and use appropriate tags to format code.

Comment: Use [this article](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) for help.

Comment: Could you include the error or other information on what happens in the controller? What specifically is the problem you are having?

Comment: <input type="text" name="name[name]">
<?php echo form_error('name[name]'); ?><input type="text" name="name[name]">
<?php echo form_error('name[age]'); ?> i want validate them using form_validation();

Answer (score 0):

you don't repeat the name inside the brackets, they are kept empty like:

```
   <input type="text" name="name[]">
    <?php echo form_error('name[]'); ?>
```

Validation

```
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('name[]','name','required');
```

note you only would do this if the form field 'name' is occurring more then once in the form.

Comment: actually i am doing same work in core php and its working great, you can see "view-source:https://www.kickstarter.com/signup?ref=nav" text box names

Comment: i think kickstarter is using ruby and javascript. if you want to use codeigniter then suggest you work through the tutorial in the codeigniter  manual.